# docker-compose: ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

Tags: python

My setup was working fine but for some reason `docker-compose --help` now yields:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/docker-compose", line 7, in <module>
    from compose.cli.main import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/compose/cli/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    from inspect import getdoc
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

Comment: please add a gist of your code so people understand the problem well.

Comment: @kishore I'm not running any code, the output I posted in my question is the full output I receive upon executing `docker-compose --help`; anyway, I've already fixed the problem but had to search quite some time so I wanted to make it easier for others with the same problem to find a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find /usr -name '*.pyc' -delete` fixed the problem.

> If you get that error, the compiled version of the Python module (the .pyc file) is corrupt probably. Gentoo Linux provides python-updater, but in Debian the easier way to fix: just delete the .pyc file. If you don't know the pyc, just delete all of them (as root):

(reference: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/17141)

Comment: Adding onto this, the root issue is that the pyc file is outdated or corrupted, because Python internally uses `marshal` to create part of `.pyc` files from `CodeObject`s, and if `marshal` can't read the type, it will throw `ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)`.